# Laravel, how to add glyphicon?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, icons

I can't do something like this:
`<a href="/home/add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Create new Gallery</a>`

I have this and I don't known what next:

```
    {{ link_to('video' ~ '/edit/' ~ video.id, trans('gallery.create'), {'class': 'btn btn-success'})}}
```

I need to add this-> `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>` to my link_to.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have a named route to this link? If so, use Laravel's helper  class <a href="{{route('routename', id)}}" class="...">

Comment: Are you talking PHP for sure?

Comment: He is using TwigBridge: https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge#extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL::to('/home/add')` to get just a link instead of using link_to() :

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/home/add') }}" class="btn btn-success">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Create new Gallery
</a>
```

Comment: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected)

Answer (score 0):

You should name your routes, it's good practice because if you ever change the url you then only have to change it in your routes.php file.

`Route::get('/home/add', ['uses' => 'YourController@action', 'as' => 'home.add']);`

Then you can just use `{{ URL::route('home.add') }}`.

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('home.add') }}" class="btn btn-success">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> 
 Create new Gallery
</a>
```

If you need to send some $id or something with the link then `{{ URL::route('home.add', ['just put those parameters in here']) }}`.

Other than that I see no way to get the glyphicon html through the $title of link_to without being escaped.

Comment: add in routes.php `Route::get('/foto/create', array('as' => 'foto.create', 'uses' => 'VideoController@getCreate'));` and in viws/nam.twig add this: `<a href="{{ URL::route('/foto/create') }}" class="btn btn-success">
  `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> 
  Create new Gallery
 </a>` and i have still error: `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected)`

Comment: 'foto.create', you named it now so no '/' but a '.' : `'as' => 'foto.create'`.  `<a href="{{ URL::route('foto.create') }}" class="btn btn-success">`

Comment: okej, I add  <a href="{{ URL::route('foto.create') }}" class="btn btn-success"> but still wrong.

Comment: `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected) in "/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/config/../views/foto/list.twig" at line 18`

Comment: Your error appears to be related to Twig:   http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1272 <- start reading at comment #20 (displayed top right of each comment)

Comment: Try `{{ URL_route('foto.create') }}` instead.

Comment: `the function "URL_route" does not exist in "/var/www/httpdocs/app/config/../views/foto/list.twig" at line 18`

Comment: Well, I've never used Twig. Just looked at the docs and it said to do it like that. You should edit your question to include that you are using Twig, maybe someone else knows.

Comment: According to this github page: https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge#extensions   "The following helpers/filters are added by the default Extensions. They are based on the helpers and/or facades, so should be self explaining." * "url_* (All the URL::* methods, snake_cased)"

Comment: I can't, as I said I never used Twig. Are you using the one I linked to in my last post? Because everything after that link is copied straight from their page. What I showed you before is how it is done when using Blade, what I showed you after that is how I assume it's done when using Twig (based on readme from git). They say `url::*` == `url_*`, so then it would have to be `{{URL_route('foto.create')}}` instead of `{{URL::route('foto.create')}}`.